# Do a query for uniqueness in MongoDB and insert if unique

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, atomic

I'm totally new to MongoDB. I'm using Morphia to access it from Java. 
I need to do something along the lines of this:

public boolean isUnique(short s){
    //OPERATION 1: Check in mongo if object with field "id" = s exists
    //if so, return false
    //else,
    //OPERATION 2: create this object in the database
    //and return true
}

The problem for me to grasp is not the actual syntax, but the problem with atomicity. How do I assure that only one thread/process can have access to the document so that OP1 and OP2 are atomic?
I think this has to be managed on a database level since the Java server is in a clustered environment.

Regards,
Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace both operations with one [upsert](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%7B%7Bupserts%7D%7D) of the {id: s} document that becomes a no-op if the document already exists, but an insert if it doesn't.  Calling the [`getLastError`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command) command (the driver can do this for you) will tell you whether a new document was created or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Java and Morphia so here is what the actual code looks like, if anyone should be wanting to achieve the same thing in the future. It's the `true` in the call to `updateFirst` that tell Mongo that it's an upsert:

```
public boolean checkIfExistsAndInsertOtherwise(short id){
    Datastore datastore = getDatastore();
    Query<OrganizationId> updateQuery = datastore.createQuery(OrganizationId.class).field("identificationNumber").equal(id);

    //Bogus operation, just set id to itself
    UpdateOperations<OrganizationId> ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(OrganizationId.class).set("identificationNumber", id);

    UpdateResults<OrganizationId> result = datastore.updateFirst(updateQuery, ops, true,WriteConcern.SAFE);

    return result.getInsertedCount() == 0;
  }
```